# .idea/shelf/Uncommitted_changes_before_Update in Android Studio

Tags: git, android-studio, intellij-idea

What is this file and why is it created? should I put this is `.gitignore`?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see [what files can be/should be shared in .idea folder](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems)

You need to add shelf folder to .gitignore

Files that you observe are shelve files, they are created when you run "Update project" and there are some uncommited changes exists, so IDE place it in shelf and then unshelve them.
It is configured under ["Clean working tree using"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-version-control-git.html) in Preferences | Version Control | Git